# How do you remove/disable Evolution Data Server process

Tags: linux, opensuse, evolution

I want to stop evolution-data-server-2.24 from loading at startup. I tried to uninstall all evolution related items, but I got some nasty warnings about removing the data server so I left it installed.

There are no items in my startup list that look like they could be it. I'm running openSUSE 11.1, if it matters,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, Evolution Data Server is a required component for Gnome and should not be used.

> The Evolution Data Server provides a single database for common, desktop-wide information, such as a user's address book or calendar events. It is also a dependency of the clock applet from the gnome-applets package, 2.10 release.

So in short, removing Evolution Data Server would either remove alot of other programs, or completely bork your install.

From the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=5b7dacb7f188e7767fc4e69e56869e6d&p=410084&postcount=3):

> It's also not a big memory loss; the little volume applet on the panel takes far more real ram than evolution-data-server.

Comment: Can I keep it from loading on startup with out harming the system?

Comment: No, I do not think you can. All these programs rely on the dataserver running to function currently. Just leave it running. It shouldn't hurt anything

Answer (score 0):

I did `yum remove "gnome*" "evolution*"` on my Fedora Core 24 system which removes MANY other things (234 total in my case; I also know that yum redirects to dnf, but yum still works fine for now), and then rebooted. In my case I had to `yum install fvwm` to get fvwm2 back. Your situation may differ in terms of what to reinstall after reboot. This is an extreme solution, but did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple method that will temporarily disable evolution (until next package update):

```bsh
sudo mv /usr/lib/evolution-data-server /usr/lib/evolution-data-server-disabled
sudo mv /usr/lib/evolution /usr/lib/evolution-disabled
```

The less dirty hack is to disable the binary to keep it from starting on future core package updates:

```bsh
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this: since these evolution services are required for Gnome DE to work, you may not be able to use your system after changing this.

Another way of doing this is to disable systemctl (for user) services related to evolution:

```
systemctl --user list-unit-files | grep evolution
```

and then for each service:

```
systemctl --user disable --now <service-name>.service
```

In case any issues, re-install the `evolution-data-server` package, e.g.:

```
apt --reinstall install evolution-data-server
```